# How to insert a list of object into mongodb using morphia?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

Hi i am trying to insert a `List<User> usrList` list of object to mongodb using mongodb morphia. I have searched but didn't get anything how to do it. Please help.
This is my user pojo class.

```
@Entity("user")
public class User {

    @Id
    ObjectId id;

    private String name;
    private String rollno;

    public String name() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String rollno() {
        return rollno;
    }
    public void setRollno(String rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }
    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(ObjectId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

this is main class which call servic to save the list of user object.

```
public static void main(String[]args){

        ApplicationContext context =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        MongoPersistenceService persistenceService = (MongoPersistenceService) context.getBean("persistenceService");
List<User> userLst = new ArrayList<User>();
        User user2 = new User();
        user2.setName("sdfhs");
        user2.setRollno("232123");
        user2.setId(new ObjectId());
        userLst.add(user2);
        persistenceService.addOrUpdateObject(userLst);
}
```

And this is my service method which i want to use .

```
 private Datastore ds;
    private AdvancedDatastore ads;
    public void addOrUpdateObject(List<?> objLst) {
                ads.insert(objLst);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly insert anything in Morphia.

Simply add all elements to your list in Java and save the whole entity with Morphia.

**Update**: Entities need a no-args constructor for Morphia to persist them. Add

```
public User(){
    super();
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class com.zymr.mongo.model.User
 at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:299)
 at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putIterable(BasicBSONEncoder.java:324)
 at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:263)
 at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:194)
 at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:136)
 at com.mongodb.DefaultDBEncoder.writeObject(DefaultDBEncoder.java:36)

Comment: Like this error comes when i tried to insert the list directly. User is pojo class havind just string name and string rollno.

Comment: Can you add all the relevant code (entity and save) to the original question?

Comment: Yes please have a look. Actually i am migrating a mongoPersistenceservice written in mongo spring data to morphia spring

Comment: You're missing the no-args constructor. I've updated my answer

Comment: No that too didnt work ...even i have tried implementing Serializable interface to User class but same error...

Comment: From what I understand `save` will overwrite documents if they have the same `_id`. Is there a way to change this behavior? I would prefer an exception be thrown.

Comment: I don't think this is possible; upserts are just the intended way. You might be able to use the optimistic locking (`@Version`) for your problem, though that's definitely hacky.

Comment: @xeraa  how do we handle duplicates while saving a list. ( when i am inserting a list of documents, i want the datastore.save(list) to save only those which are not already present.

Comment: @zee use a Set instead of a List — but this is a Java topic and not specific to Morphia or MongoDB